# Time to unlock this, perhaps?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, specific-answer, locked-posts

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/70345

Locked since August 2019, by a moderator who is no longer a moderator, to resolve disputes with a CM team which probably no longer has the employees it did then. The lock has effectively expired and should be removed.

Edit: I don't want to change the answer. I merely want it to be removed from limbo.

Comment: Do you want to change something in that answer?

Comment: No, but if the "dispute about content" hasn't been resolved by now, it never will be, so the lock should be removed. And if it has been, the lock should be removed. Ergo, the lock should be removed.

Comment: @IanKemp Incidentally I hold the opposite view: If the dispute hasn't been resolved; and people are bringing it up (indicating they want to change something about it), then that would be precisely the worst time to unlock it.

Comment: I'd roll it back to rev1, remove FAQ tag and lock as "historical content". The root problem was trying to bend this answer into a FAQ answer, if the wording wasn't ok, it had no reason to become FAQ at all.

Comment: The original answer is so iconic, it's one of the first things I remember reading when I first joined SO. It's a real "shame" that it's hidden now.

Comment: Content dispute lock was removed.

Comment: Thank you @SamuelLiew!

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the dispute has been resolved, and they came to the conclusion that the answer is as it should be, now.

Considering the crazy [edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/261593/revisions) on that answer, I see no harm in just keeping it locked to prevent further messing about.

Unlocking it for the sake of having it unlocked doesn't seem like a good idea to me on an answer that has historically been a, well, battleground.

Either way, you should really (also) flag the answer for mod attention. Moderators are more likely to find that than a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question. Make sure you link to this question in the flag.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but flagging serves to make the moderators aware of a problem. The OP wants community input, so a question is more appropriate (though I disagree with the "need" of unlocking that answer).

Comment: @yivi: We need moderators to unlock that post. The request to unlock that has nothing to do with the community, hence my line about flagging it. Community input can't be applied while the post is locked ;-)

Comment: We discuss things that only moderators can do fairly often. Moderators can take community feedback into account to make decisions.

Comment: True, but it’s quite possible that this meta question doesn’t get enough activity for a mod to notice it. I personally would flag the answer, and since this question exists now, add a link here in the flag.

Comment: The mod who commented the lock even says it will be unlocked. Since  the mod status was resigned in the meantime, it probably got forgotten/overlooked. I see nothing wrong with a request to revisit and at least clean up that comment...

Comment: I let the CM team know about it in two venues (TL and SO Chat, IIRC), and they affirmatively said they'd look into it. I assume with everything that happened in the meantime it was dropped.  Maybe change the question to ask "has the CM team had a chance to review this verbiage? and does it meet with the CoC and ToS?"